# ISSUU: Upload not working - Response Code: 999 Internal server error

Tags: php, api, publishing, issuu

I'm trying to upload files via the API (issuu.document.upload). It worked in the past. But on new files I receive always the following response error:

```
{"rsp":{"_content":{"error":{"code":"999","message":"a66125aeaff42e3a893a985fdc9b659587880484 - Internal server error"}},"stat":"fail"}}
```

The document also does not show up in "My Publications" (http://issuu.com/home/publications)

There is no API documentation about this error code...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved (the ISSUU developers fixed it). From the ISSUU support team: "***... It seems like there was some problems with our API servers, ...***"